# Java Inheritance: How to remove items from an ArrayList depending on a property which is not owned by all of the items?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, subclass, superclass

I am wondering how to edit my code so that I can remove items in the cleanShelf method depeding on not only whether the items have passed their use by date but also on whether they have already been open. The problem is that the property dateOpened is only owned by items of type DiaryFood and I don't know how to access it in my Shelf class.

Food:

```
public abstract class Food {

    private String name;
    private int calorieAmount;
    private int useDate;

    public Food(String name, int calorieAmount, int useDate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.calorieAmount = calorieAmount;
        this.useDate = useDate;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getuseDate() {
        return useDate;
    }
}
```

DiaryFood:

```
public class DiaryFood extends Food {

    private int dateOpened;

    public DiaryFood(String name, int calorieAmount, int useDate, int dateOpened) {
        super(name, calorieAmount, useDate);
        this.dateOpened = dateOpened;
    }

    public int getdateOpened() {
        return dateOpened;
    }
}
```

VegFood:

```
public class VegFood extends Food {

    private String colour;

    public VegFood(String name, int calorieAmount, int useDate, String colour) {
        super(name, calorieAmount, useDate);
        this.colour = colour;
    }

}
```

Shelf:

```
public class Shelf {

    ArrayList<Food> food;

    public Shelf() {
        food = new ArrayList<Food>();
    }


    public void addFood(Food product) {
        this.food.add(product);
    }

    public void printShelfDetails() {
        for (Food f : food)
        {
            System.out.println(f.getName() + " " + f.getuseDate());
        }
    }

    public void cleanShelf(int day) {

        ArrayList<Food> foodToRemove = new ArrayList<Food>();

        for (int i = 0; i < food.size(); i++) {
            if (food.get(i).getuseDate() < day) {
                foodToRemove.add(food.get(i));
            }
        }

        food.removeAll(foodToRemove);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You should check if the item is `instance` of `DiaryFood` and do appropriate dateOpened check
2. `cleanShelf` method is not very efficient. Using `iterator` or `removeIf` is better and cleaner choice for deleting elements from the list.

Please, see the code below

```
food.removeIf(item -> item.getuseDate() < day
            || (item instanceof DiaryFood && ((DiaryFood) item).dateOpened < day));
```

or

```
Iterator<Food> iterator = food.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Food item = iterator.next();
    if (item.getuseDate() < day
            || (item instanceof DiaryFood 
                && ((DiaryFood) item).dateOpened < day )) {
            iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go on manipulating `Food` declared types and you want to avoid manipulating specific types in your collection and or doing downcasts to `DiaryFood`, you could add a method `getDateOpened()` in the `Food` class that returns `null`.

You should change the returned type from `int` value to `Integer` value in order to be able to return a `null` value :

```
public abstract class Food {
       public Integer getdateOpened() {
         return null;
       }
}
```

In concrete classes that have effectively a `dateOpened` field, you can override it :

```
@Override
public Integer getdateOpened() {
    return dateOpened;
}
```

And of course, in the other concrete classes that have not a `dateOpened` field you can keep the implementation of the base class : `Food`.

In this way, in the loop you could do :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < food.size(); i++) {
        Foot currentFood = food.get(i);
        if (currentFood.getuseDate() < day && currentFood.getDateOpened() != null && yourConditionAboutDateOpened) {
            foodToRemove.add(food.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest this method. It adds an overhead to the public api in a way. Why not suggest the use of an `interface` instead?

Comment: interface or not, if don't want to cast you have to change the api. All depends on what the user want : doing casts or opening the contract. That's why I precised it in my answer.

Comment: @Adowrath no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `instanceof` and casting may look simple with a couple of classes, but imagine if you had 10 `Food` subclasses, each with its own remove logic.

Adding the method `getDateOpened()` to the `Food` class, making it return `null` in classes that don't have the `dateOpened` attribute adds unnecessary complexity to your interface. Users will have to know that for some `Food` subclasses this method will return a valid value and for others it won't. It also doesn't scale well on the number of subclasses.

One option that is typesafe is to move the logic that decides that some type of food should be removed to that type itself.

For example, create the method `shouldBeRemoved(int)` in the `Food` class:

```
public abstract class Food {
    public boolean shouldBeRemoved(int day) {
        return this.useDate < day;
    }
}
```

And then override it in the `DiaryFood` class, taking the `dateOpened` attribute into account:

```
public class DiaryFood extends Food {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldBeRemoved(int day) {
        return this.getUseDate() < day || this.dateOpened < day;
    }
}
```

So, in the `Shelf` class you can do:

```
public void cleanShelf(int day) {
    ArrayList<Food> foodToRemove = new ArrayList<Food>();
    for (int i = 0; i < food.size(); i++) {
        if (food.get(i).shouldBeRemoved(day)) {
            foodToRemove.add(food.get(i));
        }
    }
    food.removeAll(foodToRemove);
}
```

If you are using Java 8, this last method could simply be:

```
public void cleanShelf(int day) {
    food.removeIf(food -> food.shouldBeRemoved(day));
}
```

Comment: Two things: DiaryFood cannot use `this.useDate` since it's private in the parent class. And, I think you should mention that this, in a way, complicates things because now it isn't the shelf that decides "Hey, I don't want this food anymore!", but it's the food that says "Hey, I don't fit anymore!". Depending on the project you're working on, this may not be a concern at all or a really, *really* big one.